How would I bootstrap the lmer model?
I am trying to bootstrap (non-parametric) my lmer model, but I am struggling as to how to specify the formula when the response variables are in columns 18:1543 ( 5:10 for example data). I've tried both the parlapply below and also foreach to no avail.
To run the model without bootstrapping
library(lme4)
library(parallel)
cl <- makeCluster(3)
clusterEvalQ(cl, library(lme4))
clusterExport(cl, varlist = c("df1"))

out <- parLapply(cl, df1[, 5:10],  function(i){
    mod <- lmer(i ~ Timepoint + smoking + Gender + 
                                    (1 + Timepoint|subject), 
      data = df1, REML=T, na.action=na.omit)
      summary_mod <- summary(mod)
      coef_tbl <- as.data.frame(summary_mod$coefficients)
  
})

To run it with bootstrapping:
num_boots <- 1000 ## 500 to practice 

bootstrap_results <- parLapply(cl, 1:num_boots, function(...) {
     # Sample with replacement from your original dataset
    boot_data <- df1[sample(nrow(df1), replace = TRUE), ]
    # Fit the model using the bootstrap sample
    fit_model(boot_data)
})

I'm trying to modify the above out, to get the function fit_model for the bootstrapping, but I keep running into errors - any pointers on how to specify the function fit_model to use what be appreciated.
EDIT : I would like to be able to plot the 95% confidence intervals from the bootstrapping ( so will need to include predict to get the
predicted responses from each of the models). The initial out, gets a list of 6, each corresponding to a response variable in the example data below, each list contains the estimate, std.error etc.
structure(list(ID_new = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), levels = c("1", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", 
"8", "10", "11", "12", "16", "17", "19", "21", "22", "25", "26", 
"28", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "42", "43", "44", "45", 
"46", "48", "50", "51", "52", "55", "56", "57", "58", "61", "65", 
"71"), class = "factor"), smoking = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), levels = c("0", "1", "2"), class = "factor"), 
Gender = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), levels = c("Female", "Male"), class = "factor"), 
Timepoint = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 7L), X32 = c(-0.008670416, -0.01128918, -0.011166366, 
-0.009159031, -0.010375162, -0.00774225, -0.009165724, 0.000521958, 
-0.007122539, -0.007308026, -0.010801233, -0.003854724, -0.010839479, 
-0.004022802, -0.009357829, -0.009816342, 0.000186059, -0.000704742, 
-0.008600791, -0.004868008, -0.003739852, -0.011202195, -0.010817268, 
-0.006122522, -0.01074386, -0.007566321, -0.009815068, -0.011385987
), X35.09 = c(-0.166103202, 0.033669621, -0.023176365, -0.071449134, 
-0.108714757, 0.004155731, -0.048150734, 0.003622729, 0.020188116, 
-0.028737025, -0.037452628, 0.012795281, -0.006105379, 0.006954686, 
-0.021474094, -0.042244056, 0.02968669, -0.02677388, 0.003935916, 
0.017223254, 0.004137742, -0.170384278, -0.116611048, 0.019482532, 
-0.002876621, -0.005525266, -0.053493294, -0.008808234), 
X37 = c(-0.092375651, 0.014222991, -0.019373156, -0.030924078, 
-0.063312516, -0.007367251, -0.026851532, 0.004783281, 0.005276492, 
-0.018345841, -0.01306245, 0.002794576, -0.005272235, 0.001146375, 
-0.010851201, -0.025073805, 0.013917748, -0.022704653, 0.002380341, 
0.009607108, 0.008635899, -0.099592468, -0.06532988, 0.010469228, 
0.000635682, -0.001070113, -0.026170024, -0.008468025), X42.09 = c(-0.004668507, 
-0.00235, -0.004889642, -0.004639619, 2.59e-05, 0.00267191, 
-0.002792169, -0.003475463, -0.00318926, 0.001106193, -1.2e-05, 
-0.002010915, 0.000418124, 0.001733857, -0.005404576, -0.003165661, 
-0.001487786, -0.00067087, -0.002173524, -0.003600224, -0.003246338, 
-0.006758593, -0.004651632, -0.002759891, -0.001407011, 8.47e-05, 
0.00167546, 0.024353139), X45.09 = c(-0.048798124, 0.229832899, 
0.116725029, -0.040816946, 0.021113773, 0.011296875, -0.064347786, 
-0.065139151, -0.054111259, -0.061023034, 0.100101089, -0.0609503, 
0.117890757, -0.068498075, -0.006683723, -0.011630944, -0.021409441, 
-0.021778981, -0.036247739, -0.031283777, 0.023295127, -0.04456303, 
-0.081122758, -0.025794646, 0.159131723, 0.094266912, -0.069028563, 
0.130724578), X46.09 = c(-0.032880735, 0.000830199, -0.000484781, 
-0.009031697, 0.030243962, 0.064887696, -0.041325222, 0.008345214, 
-0.003883789, -0.00572648, 0.015770933, 0.087383316, -0.005755213, 
0.003283089, -0.017003641, 0.032150245, -0.022737774, -0.031740282, 
-0.002695395, -0.013914, -0.016015172, -0.016867542, -0.007686406, 
-0.018295116, 0.028014044, 0.006110395, 0.009576921, 0.078189301
)), row.names = c(NA, 28L), class = "data.frame")


I don't understand. What do you mean "the response variables are in columns 18:1543" ? The response variable in a regression model is the outcome, so you seem to be saying that you have 1525 different outcome variables. Also, please provide a minimum working example.

@RobertLong , yes, you're correct, in total there are 1526 responses, and a model is being individually fit to each one. I'm sorry, I've included example data now, which only includes 6 responses but the initial parlapply code (without bootstrapping) works.

@BenBolker thank you for your comment, yes, I'm working on the fit_model function at the moment, I think it might be easier to generate the 1000 bootstrapped samples separately, then apply the function to each of these and get the predictions, then calculate CI, because I can't get the fit_model function to work. WIll update the post with making clusters and exporting the cluster, so hopefully the first part will become more reproducible

@BenBolker I just realised you've beaten me to it, thank you for your edits.

When you have structured data you really ought to be using a structured bootstrap, e.g. from the lmeresampler package.
Using df1 from the post:
library(lme4)
library(lmeresampler)
library(parallel)
library(broom.mixed)

## fit a baseline model so we can refit() internally
lme0 <- lmer(X32 ~ Timepoint + smoking + Gender + 
                 (1 + Timepoint|ID_new),
             data = df1, REML=TRUE, na.action=na.omit)

cl <- makeCluster(3)
invisible(clusterEvalQ(cl, sapply(c("lme4", "broom.mixed", "lmeresampler"),
                        library, character.only = TRUE)))
clusterExport(cl, varlist = c("df1", "lme0"))


out <- parLapply(cl, df1[, 5:10],  function(i) {
    m1 <- refit(lme0, i)
    tt <- tidy(m1, effects = "fixed")
    cb <- case_bootstrap(m1, 
                         .f = predict,
                         B = 100, 
                         ## resample subjects and observations within subjects
                         resample = c(TRUE, TRUE),
                         orig_data = df1, .refit = TRUE)
    ci <- confint(cb)
    list(tt, cb, ci)
})

The function shown here (1) has more bits than you probably need (e.g., maybe you're happy saving just the bootstrap confidence intervals?); (2) if you wanted to get confidence intervals on coefficients rather than predictions the bootstrap would fail at the last step (computing confidence intervals) because the data set is too small so some bootstrap samples end up without observations from both genders. (If that's a problem in your real data set you'll have to figure out how to do a more stratified bootstrap ...)
